# Rust E0506 (assignment to borrowed value): "borrow later used here" on seemingly unrelated expression

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to make a rudimentary linked list implementation using `Option` and `Box` without `unsafe` mode, and I encountered this particularly strange error when attempting to make a method to remove all nodes with a particular value.

I was able to reproduce the error with a simplified example (some types annotated for clarity):

```rust
struct Node {
    should_remove: bool,
    next_node: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct SinglyLinkedList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl SinglyLinkedList {
    fn remove_certain_nodes(&mut self) {
        let mut current_node_link = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(current_node /* &mut Box<Node> */) = current_node_link {
            if current_node.should_remove {
                // Remove the node by replacing the link to the current node with the link to the next node
                let next_node_link = current_node.next_node.take();
                std::mem::drop(current_node); // The error is the same with or without this
                *current_node_link = next_node_link;
                // current_node_link already points to the next node, so it doesn't need to be advanced
            }
            else {
                current_node_link = &mut current_node.next_node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this gives the error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*current_node_link` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
13 |         while let Some(current_node /* &mut Box<Node> */) = current_node_link {
   |                        ------------ `*current_node_link` is borrowed here
...
18 |                 *current_node_link = next_node_link;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 `*current_node_link` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
   |                 borrow later used here
```

Most of the time, Rust is fine with doing something which would violate a borrow as long as the borrow isn't used again afterwards. The error seems to indicate that the expression `*current_node_link` somehow reuses the borrow related to `current_node`, which I can't think of an explanation for.

I tried doing a manual `drop` of `current_node`, as shown in the code, but it doesn't seem to help.

What is the reasoning here for the borrow being "used" in the expression `*current_node_link`? And is there a way I can restructure my logic to avoid this issue?

**EDIT:** This is related to a borrow checker limitation that is solved in nightly with Polonius. This [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51545) has more detail. Since I am avoiding nightly features, my current workaround is simply replacing the `while let` condition with `while current_node_link.is_some()` and replacing the instances of `current_node` with `current_node_link.as_mut().unwrap()`, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, nightly rustc accepts this code with `-Zpolonius`, so you can attribute this error to a bug / design issue in the current borrow checker. If/when Polonius lands, this code will work as-is (without the `drop` even).

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for letting me know! Upon further searching just now I found [a post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-explain-this-cannot-assign-to-xxx-because-it-is-borrowed-error/80090/3) on the rust-lang forum that has a similar issue, and Polonius is also brought up there. "The only reason this doesn't compile is because the compiler isn't yet clever enough to figure out that it should."

Comment: I believe the standard workaround for this limitation is to use recursion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=affe5ad9ca0ae47021851e11a3d27302

Comment: @user4815162342 TCO isn't guaranteed though, right? So this could blow up the stack on a large list.

Comment: @cdhowie It's not, and it could. But it might still be the only way to do it without unsafe, and acceptable for lists known (expected) to be short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is accepted by Polonius, the next-generation borrow checker, it is probably valid, barring a Polonius bug. Still, the current borrow checker misdetects it as flawed. One way to work around the borrow checker limitations in understanding loops is to switch to recursion. This code, for example, is accepted:

```
fn remove_certain_nodes(&mut self) {
    fn helper(current_node_link: &mut Option<Box<Node>>) {
        let Some(current_node) = current_node_link else {
            return;
        };
        if current_node.should_remove {
            let next_node_link = current_node.next_node.take();
            *current_node_link = next_node_link;
            helper(current_node_link);
        }
        else {
            helper(&mut current_node.next_node);
        }
    }
    helper(&mut self.head);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=affe5ad9ca0ae47021851e11a3d27302)

As always with recursive calls, you need to watch out for stack overflows, no pun intended. This code uses tail calls (even accounting for drops), which the optimizer can be expected to convert to a loop, and that [seems to be the case](https://godbolt.org/z/j4s83G6vM) here. But elimination of tail calls is not guaranteed by Rust, and [isn't done](https://godbolt.org/z/orYPqcTrh) in debug builds, so you need to be careful.